# How to stop spammer querying WordPress site with particular URL ending in .ASP

Tags: php, url, spam

Some spammers or maybe hackers query my WordPress site with bots using particular URL ending in .ASP. For example:
/bokeindex.asp
/Class/Post.asp
/CreateUser.asp

Currently my site gives a 404 and I get the log of such visits from "404 Redirected" plugin. I use the ip-address from the log and ban it in cpanel using "IP Deny Manager." But it is a painfully time consuming process and I looked for some other solution. IP or country banning was not an optimum solution. After some searches I got an idea to use the below code in the index.php of WordPress root.

```
<?php
    if (stristr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.asp')) 
    {
        die();
    }
?>
```

My question is - is this a safe method?

If it is, I would want to further extend it to read from a list of rogue URLs. What do you think of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do that on the server level, not in WordPress. Example for .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch Permanent \.(asp|ASP) http://localhost
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought of putting it in WordPress because there are hundreds of such URLs - tens of them attacking daily, which prompts me to perhaps extend the 404-Redirected plugin. Do you think it's fine to have hundreds of such statements in .htaccess? And do I put them in the beginning, before the WordPress rewrite statements?

Comment: .htaccess rules are processed in order of appearance, so yes, put this before the WordPress rules. .htaccess rules are always processed faster than anything in PHP. You can combine multiple “bad” URLs in a single regex, so this shouldn’t be a problem.

Comment: One more query please. I am getting bad URLs like "mydomain.com/?xyz=print-439573653*57;&pu5=print-439573653*57;&pu5=print-4395736‌​53*57;" I want to weed out this URL by matching even one occurrence of the string "=print" anywhere in the URL. How to construct the regex pattern for that? I tried from examples but either it's ignored or it gives Internal Server Error.